# Define variables for specific template

Tags: theming

I would like to pass variables to a single specific template file(tpl.php).
My setting is the following:

my_entities.module

```
function my_entities_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path) {
  return array(
    'my_entities_property' => array(
      'variables' => array('element' => null),
      'template' => 'my-entities-property'
    )
  );
}
```

I am using a template file at my_theme/templates/my-entities-property.tpl.php

In the module file I am trying to invoke a preprocess function to add a variable but it is not being invoked.

```
function template_preprocess_my_entities_property(&$variables) {
  $variables['test'] = "test";
}
```

How could I make this work?  I followed https://www.drupal.org/node/2275895#comment-8832701 but it seems that I am doing something wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should put your template in your module as well.

```
my_theme/templates/my-entities-property.tpl.php
```

Make sure to update your theme function like this :

```
function my_entities_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path) {
  return array(
    'my_entities_property' => array(
      'variables' => array('element' => null),
      'template' => 'my-entities-property',
      'path' => drupal_get_path('module', 'my_entities') . '/templates'
    )
  );
}
```

Try to use THEME_preprocess_my_entities_property(&$variables) in template.php instead.

Comment: Using both dpm and watchdog to register activity nothing happens.

Comment: Where do you use your dpm ?

Comment: In the function to check that it goes in.

Comment: In your module do you also have your template in my_entities_theme/my-entities-property.tpl.php ?

Comment: As I described before the tpl.php is place at my_theme/templates/my-entities-property.tpl.php. Does that make a difference?

Comment: I think in order to declare a Drupal template you should always put it in your module and then if you want to override put it again in your theme folder. Try to put it in my_entities_theme/templates/my-entities-property.tpl.php

Answer (score 1):

In module preprocess function is `moduleName_preprocess_[theme_function_hook]`.
here it will be my_entities_preprocess_my_entities_property

Comment: Using both dpm and watchdog to register activity nothing happens.